# Is it possible to remove the SSH delay in order to work with VIM through it?

Tags: networking, ssh, vim

I'm trying to write programs using VIM on a remote server. The server is necessary because I'm in a system without VIM (iOS). When I connect through SSH, there is a visible delay of 200~600ms, which makes coding barely unpractical. Is there any way to use VIM remotely without that delay?

Comment: Coding on a tablet isn't very practical anyway. Get yourself a laptop.

Comment: Any reason you're tied to VIM? Surely there's any number of suitable iOS editors.

Comment: No it is not. See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53988/slow-typing-on-ipad

Answer (score 1):

You should understand what causes the delay.  It is probably caused by [excessive buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat) in your routers, in which case you should try to eliminate it.

If you cannot reduce the delay, using [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/) instead of ssh may hide some of it.